# strcat adds junk to the string

Tags: c, string, c-strings, strcat

I'm trying to reverse a sentence, without changing the order of words,

For example: "Hello World" => "olleH dlroW"

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverseWords(const char *text);
char * reverseWord(char *word);

int main () {
  char *text = "Hello World";
  char *result = reverseWords(text);
  char *expected_result = "olleH dlroW";
  printf("%s == %s\n", result, expected_result);
  printf("%d\n", strcmp(result, expected_result));
  return 0;
}

char *
reverseWords (const char *text) {
  // This function takes a string and reverses it words.
  int i, j;
  size_t len = strlen(text);
  size_t text_size = len * sizeof(char);
  // output containst the output or the result
  char *output;

  // temp_word is a temporary variable,
  // it contains each word and it will be
  // empty after each space.
  char *temp_word;

  // temp_char is a temporary variable,
  // it contains the current character
  // within the for loop below.
  char temp_char;

  // allocating memory for output.
  output = (char *) malloc (text_size + 1);

  for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    // if the text[i] is space, just append it
    if (text[i] == ' ') {
      output[i] = ' ';
    }

    // if the text[i] is NULL, just get out of the loop
    if (text[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    }

    // allocate memory for the temp_word
    temp_word = (char *) malloc (text_size + 1);

    // set j to 0, so we can iterate only on the word
    j = 0;

    // while text[i + j] is not space or NULL, continue the loop
    while((text[i + j] != ' ') && (text[i + j] != '\0')) {

      // assign and cast test[i+j] to temp_char as a character,
      // (it reads it as string by default)
      temp_char = (char) text[i+j];

      // concat temp_char to the temp_word
      strcat(temp_word, &temp_char); // <= PROBLEM

      // add one to j
      j++;
    }

    // after the loop, concat the reversed version
    // of the word to the output
    strcat(output, reverseWord(temp_word));

    // if text[i+j] is space, concat space to the output
    if (text[i+j] == ' ')
      strcat(output, " ");

    // free the memory allocated for the temp_word
    free(temp_word);

    // add j to i, so u can skip 
    // the character that already read.
    i += j;
  }

  return output;
}

char *
reverseWord (char *word) {
  int i, j;
  size_t len = strlen(word);
  char *output;

  output = (char *) malloc (len + 1);

  j = 0;
  for(i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    output[j++] = word[i];
  }

  return output;
}
```

The problem is the line I marked with `<= PROBLEM`, On the first word which in this case is "Hello", it does everything just fine.

On the second word which in this case is "World", It adds junky characters to the `temp_word`,
I checked it with `gdb`, `temp_char` doesn't contain the junk, but when `strcat` runs, the latest character appended to the `temp_word` would be something like `W\006`,

It appends `\006` to all of the characters within the second word,

The output that I see on the terminal is fine, but printing out `strcmp` and comparting the `result` with `expected_result` returns `-94`.

- What can be the problem?
- What's the `\006` character?
- Why `strcat` adds it?
- How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Please think about the reason you allocate `len + 1` bytes... Why is the `+1` there? Do you *use* the extra byte you allocate?

Comment: Also please think about what happens to the memory you allocate in `reverseWord`. When and where is it free'd?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually I'm a C newbie, Thanks for pointing out the thing I need to read more about, The first one, I have no Idea, The second one was one of my concerns, but ofcourse I can't `free` a variable and then return it

Comment: consider the use of the `strtok` function and how it can prevent you from leaking memory. pass the output of `strtok` to your reverse word function and then perform an in-place reversal by swapping elements of the word until the end of it is reached. How can you use the null-terminated C-string output of `strtok` to avoid carving up your RAM by using `malloc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat()` expects addresses of the 1st character of "C"-strings, which in fact are `char`-arrays with at least one element being equal to `'\0'`.

Neither the memory `temp_word` points to nor the memory `&temp_char` points to meet such requirements.

Due to this the infamous undefined behaviour is invoked, anything can happen from then on.

A possible fix would be to change

```
      temp_word = (char *) malloc (text_size + 1);
```

to become

```
      temp_word = malloc (text_size + 1); /* Not the issue but the cast is 
                                             just useless in C. */
      temp_word[0] = '\0';
```

and this

```
        strcat(temp_word, &temp_char);
```

to become

```
        strcat(temp_word, (char[2]){temp_char});
```

---

There might be other issues with the rest of the code.

Comment: It did actually work, But I can't understand how, First `temp_word[0] = '\0'`, Why are we putting a NULL pointer at the start of the string?

Comment: I meant null character*

Comment: @DarkSuniuM: Not a null-pointer but a null-character. Quoting my answer: "*"C"-strings, ... in fact are char-arrays with at least one element being equal to '\0'.*"

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of junk characters is you use wrong input for the 2nd argument of strcat function. see explain below:

At the beginning of your function you declare:

```
  int i, j;
  size_t len = strlen(text);
  size_t text_size = len * sizeof(char);
  // output containst the output or the result
  char *output;

  // temp_word is a temporary variable,
  // it contains each word and it will be
  // empty after each space.
  char *temp_word;

  // temp_char is a temporary variable,
  // it contains the current character
  // within the for loop below.
  char temp_char;
```

you can print variable's addresses in stack, they will be something like this:

```
printf("&temp_char=%p,&temp_word=%p,&output=%p,&text_size=%p\n", &temp_char, &temp_word,&output,&text_size);
result:    
&temp_char=0x7ffeea172a9f,&temp_word=0x7ffeea172aa0,&output=0x7ffeea172aa8,&text_size=0x7ffeea172ab0
```

As you can see, &temp_char(0x7ffeea172a9f) is at the bottom of the stack, next 1 byte is &temp_word(0x7ffeea172aa0), next 8 bytes is &output(0x7ffeea172aa8), and so on(I used 64bit OS, so it takes 8 bytes for a pointer)

```
 // concat temp_char to the temp_word
  strcat(temp_word, &temp_char); // <= PROBLEM
```

refer strcat description here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

the strcat second argument = &temp_char = 0x7ffeea172a9f. strcat considers that &temp_char(0x7ffeea172a9f) is the starting point of the source string, **instead of adding only one char as you expect it will append to temp_word all characters starting from &temp_char(0x7ffeea172a9f) , until it meets terminating null character**

Answer (score 1):

The function strcat deals with strings.

In this code snippet

```
  // assign and cast test[i+j] to temp_char as a character,
  // (it reads it as string by default)
  temp_char = (char) text[i+j];

  // concat temp_char to the temp_word
  strcat(temp_word, &temp_char); // <= PROBLEM
```

neither the pointer `temp_word` nor the pointer `&temp_char` points to a string.

Moreover array `output` is not appended with the terminating-zero character for example when the source string consists from blanks.

In any case your approach is too complicated and has many redundant code as for example the condition in the for loop and the condition in the if statement that duplicate each other.

```
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    //…

    // if the text[i] is NULL, just get out of the loop
    if (text[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    }
```

The function can be written simpler as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse_words( const char *s )
{
    char *result = malloc( strlen( s ) + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        char *p = result;

        while ( *s != '\0' )
        {
            while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*s ) )
            {
                *p++ = *s++;
            }


            const char *q = s;

            while ( !isblank( ( unsigned char )*q ) && *q != '\0' ) ++q;

            for ( const char *tmp = q; tmp != s; )
            {
                *p++ = *--tmp;
            }

            s = q;
        }

        *p = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "Hello World";

    char *result = reverse_words( s );

    puts( s );
    puts( result );

    free( result );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
olleH dlroW
```